# Restarting the same thread after exception thrown in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am trying to execute some code in a thread. I have extend the Thread class and put some code there to execute. I am also throwing exception to terminate the current thread and restart it in the catch block. It is doing so but when new Thread start then abnormal result is shown.

Suppose my requirement is to print counter like `1,2,3,4,5`. It is well for the first time. But when I start new Instance then the result is random something like `1,1,1,1,1,1,12,4,6,1,1,1,1`. Here is my code:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    static Publish publish;
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        publish =  new Publish();
        publish.start();
    }    
    
    static class Publish extends Thread {
    static int counter = 1;
      public void run(){
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("counter is: " + counter);
            counter++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                if (counter > 5) {
                    throw new InterruptedException("Exception thrown manually to restart thread");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                publish.interrupt();
                publish.getThreadGroup().interrupt();
                counter = 1;
                publish = new Publish();
                publish.start();
            }
        }
        
      }
  }
    
}
```

The result are like below:

```
    run:
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 8
counter is: 9
counter is: 11
counter is: 12
counter is: 12
counter is: 14
counter is: 15
counter is: 15
counter is: 17
counter is: 18
counter is: 19
counter is: 20
counter is: 1
counter is: 20
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 20
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 20
counter is: 20
counter is: 20
counter is: 20
counter is: 20
counter is: 2
counter is: 20
counter is: 20
counter is: 2
counter is: 20
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 2
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 5
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 7
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 7
counter is: 6
counter is: 9
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 6
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 4
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 5
counter is: 7
counter is: 7
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 6
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 5
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 9
counter is: 10
counter is: 11
counter is: 12
counter is: 13
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 6
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 9
counter is: 9
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
Exception in thread "Thread-260" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
    at threadtest.ThreadTest$Publish.run(ThreadTest.java:49)
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
Exception in thread "Thread-236" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
counter is: 1
    at threadtest.ThreadTest$Publish.run(ThreadTest.java:49)
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
Exception in thread "Thread-165" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
counter is: 3
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
    at threadtest.ThreadTest$Publish.run(ThreadTest.java:49)
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 6
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 5
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 9
counter is: 10
counter is: 11
counter is: 12
counter is: 13
counter is: 14
counter is: 15
counter is: 16
counter is: 17
counter is: 18
counter is: 19
counter is: 20
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
Exception in thread "Thread-156" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
    at threadtest.ThreadTest$Publish.run(ThreadTest.java:49)
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 9
counter is: 10
counter is: 11
counter is: 12
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 5
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 1
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 8
counter is: 10
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 4
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 9
counter is: 10
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 7
counter is: 9
counter is: 9
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 2
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 5
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 3
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
counter is: 6
counter is: 7
counter is: 8
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 6
```

Comment: when a Thread is stopped, you can't restart it. You can start a new Thread that is similar

Comment: You can't restart a thread. Why don't you just reuse the already running instance? What you could do is put the data and logic into a `Runnable` or  `Callable` and replace that.

Comment: You not restarting your thread. You start another one while first continue to work.

Comment: You're trying to use an exception to model your program flow, don't do that.

Comment: any idea how to do that, cause I need to restart the flow if exception occurs. My program should not stop

Comment: I don't see the point of interrupting the thread, or of interrupting the thread group.  Try removing those lines.

Comment: @markspace then how can I stop completely all the previous thread, or continue the process by avoiding program interruption.

Comment: Just exit the while loop, or `return`.

Comment: @markspace it works fine. thanks. But what happened to the previous Thread object on Publish? will they occupy memory after return?

Comment: No, threads are just heap objects.  Each `new` object gets new heap memory.  It isn't special for `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this program is that the threads are just being created and never been destroyed as you have interrupted the running thread by itself, that's where it's being messed up. The threads aren't stopping and it keeps executing as it is inside the loop. I wouldn't comment whether it is the right way to do it. But I would suggest to look for other alternatives. I have made some modification in your program as follows:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    static Publish publish;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Initial active threads : " + Thread.activeCount());
        publish = new Publish();
        publish.start();
    }

    static class Publish extends Thread {
        static int counter = 1;

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("counter is: " + counter);
                counter++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    if (counter > 5) {
                        throw new InterruptedException("Exception thrown manually to restart thread");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    counter = 1;
                    publish = new Publish();
                    publish.start();
                    System.out.println("active threads : " + Thread.activeCount());
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the program:

```
Initial active threads : 2
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
counter is: 4
counter is: 5
active threads : 4
counter is: 1
counter is: 2
counter is: 3
```

If you want to see the total threads being created and not stopping at all in your program, try placing print statement for the current active threads.